# What will be the velocities at two water taps at different heights that source water from an overhead tank? Water is flowing down only with gravity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, pressure

[image]

1. Scenario 1 - What will be the velocity at Tap 1, if Tap 2 were open?
2. Scenario 2 - What will be the velocity at Tap 1, if Tap 2 were
   closed?
3. Scenario 3 - What will be the velocity at Tap 2, if Tap 1
   were open?
4. Scenario 4 - What will be the velocity at Tap 2, if Tap 1
   were closed?

In a related question - to calculate pressures at Tap 1 an Tap 2, what are the heights to be considered? As one can see from the diagram, there are many heights involved.